# inverse problem for specific heat of fermion .. has been solved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions

hi given the specific heat is given by an integral equation

$$ C(T)=\int_{0}^{\infty}d\nu g(\nu)\frac{u^{2}}{(e^{u\nu}+1)^{2}}\nu^{2}$$

where $ u= \frac{h}{kT}$

my question is is the following problem solved ?

recover $ g(\nu) $ from knowing $ C(T) $ an inverse problem involivng an integral equation

is this problem solved ?if so where and how ?? for the case of bosons i think this problem has been solved

problem: solve the integral equation to get $ g(\nu) $

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking whether the integral has a closed form solution if one knows $g(\nu)$?  It would help if you defined $g(\nu)$ (density of states?), among other things and clear up your questions.

Comment: no on the contrary :D i ask if we knew $ C(T) $ on the left could then solve this itnegral equation and get $ g(\nu) $ ??

Comment: @kyle corrected

Comment: That is better!